# Get statusbar height on 4.0+

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, statusbar, window-managers

i am trying to ge the status bar height and it successfully works in 2.3. But when i run the same code on 4.0+, it will return as 0.

here is the code i am using...

```
Rect rectgle= new Rect();
                Window window= getWindow();
                window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
                int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
                int contentViewTop= 
                    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
                int TitleBarHeight= contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;


                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "DETERMINED STATUSBAR HEIGHT - "+TitleBarHeight;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
```

Any input would be awesome!

Comment: This doesn't work on any API version.  `StatusBarHeight` always equals 0 since `getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)` gives the entire screen, so `top` always equals 0.  I suggest you step through you code in the debugger.

Comment: I return me 0 when i tried to obtain in onCreate,because the layout doesn't know its size yet in onCreate because it hasn't finished being drawn.
What I usually do is post a Runnable on the UI thread from onCreate which gives the UI time to draw itself.
Like this i was able to get the status bar height in all versions.